# How to allow paypal payments via my custom API

Tags: api, payment

I have built my custom xml api in my rails application to enable clients purchase and manage their items. But am stuck on how to enable them pay for their domains via my custom api.

I would like them to send a request with method say "pay" and their paypal credentials to pay for a particular item.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, your API should NOT require callers to give you their PayPal credentials.

Nobody should EVER give their credentials for a given site/service (e.g. PayPal in this case) to a third-party (i.e. you).

If you want to add PayPal support to your site, read and follow PayPal's API docs, samples, etc.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/

Comment: Thanks Rich. I will surely look at the link although it is still unclear to me how I am to achieve my goal

Comment: Thousands of websites and apps use PayPal, even my Xbox and domain registrar. Look at how others do this and then figure out how to do so in your app. Note: it doesn't involve users giving YOU their creeds to PayPal

Comment: Unhelpful answer. Clearly not clever to request credentials but doesn't attempt to provide a solution. The problem clearly is how to relay a request to PayPal via an intermediate API

Comment: There is no valid solution to a scenario involving giving an unrelated 3rd party your username and password. Would be bad it it was Gmail etc. creds. Handing over PayPal creds is a nightmare waiting to hapen.